# Merge one column data in Oracle based on another two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am trying to build a report in Oracle and I am struggling to group the data by two columns (client and user) and concatenate the other one (operation).

Basically, I have this data:

| Client | Operation | User |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client A | 1 | John Smith |
| Client A | 2 | John Smith |
| Client A | 1 | Peter Brown |
| Client B | 3 | Mike Kennedy |

and this is the expected result:

| Client | Operation | User |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client A | 1;2 | John Smith |
| Client A | 1 | Peter Brown |
| Client B | 3 | Mike Kennedy |

I am trying to group the data by the columns client and user by I get the error "not a group by expression".

Can anyone help me with the query?

Comment: please edit the question and show the SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `listagg` function:

```sql
SELECT   client,
         LISTAGG(operation, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY operation),
         user
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY client, user
```

Comment: Thanks, the listagg function made the trick!